# Getting MIN Price in Subquery in SQL Server (using DISTINCT)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get a Minimun price from a car in a table i have.. I am using DISTINCT

SELECT DISTINCT

datepart(year,[Registration]) AS YearRegistered,
MIN(SalePrice), Model, Make

FROM [VehicleSales]

But its not working,  for example

without distinct returns many car makes and models so i use distinct so i get unique cars that are the same make and model and year....

I wish to incorporate a "Startign from price ..."  hence the SalePrice can also be different for same model and make ... so i want to do a MIN..

But i am bit confused, the above is working working...

Any ideas?

Comment: i am not sure i understand exactly what you want to do.. can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a GROUP BY clause and get rid of the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT 
       datepart(year,[Registration]) AS YearRegistered, 
       MIN(SalePrice), Model, Make
FROM 
       [VehicleSales] 
GROUP BY 
       datepart(year,[Registration]), Model, Make
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DATEPART(year,[Registration]) AS YearRegistered, Model, Make, MIN(SalePrice)
FROM    [VehicleSales]
GROUP BY
        DATEPART(year,[Registration]) AS YearRegistered, Model, Make
```